# Is it possible to handle TCP flags with TCP socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

With TCP protocol, is it possible to bind to a port, listen for data. And handle `TCP flags` manually?

**EDIT**

A normal program could do `socket(), bind(), then listen()` and `accept()` connections. Then you can get data from the socket, not the TCP flags, e.g PSH + ACK

Here's what I want, when a `TCP` connection is not established yet, just any packet sent to a port of a server, I want to see the TCP flags it uses, e.g `SYN`, `SYN + ACK`

**EDIT**

Yes I know about pcap and packet socket, but I didn't meant to capture packets. I mean a server listens on a port and handle the TCP flags ..

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean handle "TCP Flags"?

Comment: Do you mean on a TCP socket? Or more generally you want to see more of TCP protocol in user space (in which case a raw IP socket would offer you that)?

Comment: @nrathaus yes, even before connection is established (the 3 way handshake)

Comment: @Joe yes on a TCP socket. Can you see my update please?

Comment: You can use Pcap on Linux, and construct packets by yourself and capture the traffic using "pcap filters".

Comment: @nrathaus Is it possible without capturing packets? Just a server listening on a port

Comment: I don't believe you can create a socket that sits BELOW the kernel's "TCP handling stack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The Linux kernel handles the TCP `ACK`, `PSH`, and `SYN` flags internally, and you cannot access them.