# TCP PSH flag is not set for packets for which it should be

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel

As far as I understand from [Is it possible to handle TCP flags with TCP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132404/is-it-possible-to-handle-tcp-flags-with-tcp-socket) and what I've read so far, a server application does not handle and cannot access TCP flags at all.
And from what I've read in RFCs the PSH flag tells the receiving host's kernel to forward data from receive buffer to the application.

I've found this interesting read https://flylib.com/books/en/3.223.1.209/1/ and it mentions that "Today, however, most APIs don't provide a way for the application to tell its TCP to set the PUSH flag. Indeed, many implementors feel the need for the PUSH flag is outdated , and a good TCP implementation can determine when to set the flag by itself."

"Most Berkeley-derived implementations automatically set the PUSH flag if the data in the segment being sent empties the send buffer. This means we normally see the PUSH flag set for each application write, because data is usually sent when it's written. "

If my understanding is correct and TCPStack decides by itself using different conditions,etc. when to set the PSH flag, then what can I do if TCPStack doesn't set the PSH flag when it should?

I have a server application written in Java and client written in C, there are 1000 clients each on a separate host and they all connect to server. A mechanism which acts as a keep-alive involves server sending each 60 seconds a request to each client that requests some info. The response is always less than MTU(1500bytes) so all the time response frames should have PSH flag set.
It happened at some point that client was sending 50 replies to only one request and all of them with PSH flag not set. Buffer got full probably before the client even sent the 3rd or 4th time the same reply and receiving app thrown an exception because it received more data than it was expecting from receive buffer of host.

My question is, what can I do in such a situation if I cannot communicate at all with TCPStack?

P.S. - I know that client should not send more than 1 reply but still in normal operation all the replies have PSH flag set and in this certain situation they didn't, which is not application fault

Comment: *"receiving app thrown an exception because it received more data than it was expecting from receive buffer of host."* - This sounds like your application is assuming that PSH somehow signals the end of the message. But TCP has no message semantics but is an unstructured byte stream. And the TCP standard explicitly says that PSH should not be treated as end of message marker. If the application expects this, then it is broken.

Comment: I see, so basically as soon as data gets to the buffer server application should read it immediately if I understand correctly what you say.

Comment: No. The server application should not make any assumptions if read returns a full message, part of a message, multiple messages, some messages and then some part of another ... . What read returns should be treated as an unstructured byte stream and then one need to implement an application layer on top of it which gives this byte stream some meaning in form of messages.